# logo in Rochester header

Tags: beamer, header-footer, logos

I would like to put 2 logos at each sides of the Rochester header with the title center in between. I've redefined `\frametitle` like this :

```
\let\oldframetitle\frametitle
\renewcommand{\frametitle}[1]{
   \oldframetitle{\centering\raisebox{3mm}{
         \begin{minipage}[c]{.15\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo/logo1.png}       
         \end{minipage}
         \hfill\parbox[c][][c]{.82\textwidth}{\centering#1}\hfill
         \begin{minipage}[c]{.15\textwidth}
                    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{logo/logo2.png}                   
         \end{minipage}
     }
}}
```

I wonder why I don't get overfull hbox since 0.15+0.82+0.15 > 1 ?
Then if #1 is empty, like `\begin{frame}{}`, logos are sticked in the left corner. At last, it's may be not the best solution.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach will inevitable fail as soon as you want to enjoy all the possibilities beamer offers you, such as `\frametitle<2>{...}` or using a `\framesubtitle` etc. In my opinion the better way is to add the necessary changes to the `headline` and `frametitle` template the `Rochester` theme uses (the code can be found in `beamerouterthemesidebar.sty`).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Rochester}


\makeatletter

  \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
    \nointerlineskip%
    \vskip-\beamer@headheight%
    \vbox to \beamer@headheight{%
      %\vfil
      \leftskip=-\beamer@leftmargin%
      \advance\leftskip by2.1cm%
      \rightskip=-\beamer@rightmargin%
      \advance\rightskip by2.1cm plus1fil%
      \begin{minipage}[t][\beamer@headheight][c]{\dimexpr\paperwidth-4.2cm\relax}
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\centering\insertframetitle\par
        \usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle\par
      \end{minipage}
      \vbox{}%
      \vskip-1em%
      \vfil
    }%
  }

  \setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{frametitle}
      \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
      \else%
        \hfill%
      \fi%
      \ifdim\beamer@sidebarwidth>0pt%  
        \usebeamercolor[bg]{logo}%
        \vrule width\beamer@sidebarwidth height \beamer@headheight%
        \hskip-\beamer@sidebarwidth%
        \hbox to \beamer@sidebarwidth{\hss\vbox to
          \beamer@headheight{\vss\hbox{\color{fg}\insertlogo}\vss}\hss}%
      \else%
        \raisebox{.1\beamer@headheight}{\hspace*{0.1cm}\includegraphics[height=.8\beamer@headheight]{example-image}}
        \vrule width0pt height \beamer@headheight%  
        \hfill
        \raisebox{.1\beamer@headheight}{\includegraphics[height=.8\beamer@headheight]{example-image}}\hspace*{0.1cm}
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{frametitle}
   abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{frame title frame title  frame title  frame title frame title frame title frame title}
  abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try to guess, but you don't really answered my questions.

Comment: @dagnic This may not answer your question, but it solves the problem.

Comment: Actually, no. With long title, the text flows on the right logo. That's why I used `parbox`. Moreover, I'm not looking for an incomprehensible "built-in" solution, but for answers to my questions.

Comment: Well, how can I center the title ?